# Why does this bash script not exit if it has set -e?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand the reason this script does not exit when `bar` file does not exist. Also I'm trying to understand what `[ -f bar ]` actually does.

```sh
set -x
set -e 

[ -f bar ] && source bar

cat bar

echo $0
```

As I understand, `set -x` prints the command and its arguments before it's actually executed. `set -e` causes the script to exit if any command returns an error. Running `[ -f bar ]` locally in a terminal returns an `-1` status code when `bar` does not exist and `[ -f bar ] && source bar` returns `-1` as well. But when `bar` does exist it returns a `0` status code.

Does `[ -f bar ]` checks if the file exist or what's its purpose? I know `set -e` is working as `cat bar` actually causes the script to exit before it runs `echo $0`

The actual output is this:

```
+ set -e
+ '[' -f bar ']'
+ cat bar
cat: bar: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `set -e` doesn't affect commands that are executed  before `&&`, or `||`.

Comment: Because it would defeat the purpose of using those operators if the script exited before checking the results.

Comment: `set -e` has a lot of edge cases and confusing complexity. See [BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for some explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Like what @Barmar said in the comments, the `set -e` doesn't affect commands run before `&&` and `||`.

Formally, this's stated in the `man sh`:

> -e errexit
>
> If not interactive, exit immediately if any untested command fails.  The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly tested if the command is used to control an if, elif, while, or until; or if the command is the left hand operand of an “&&” or “||” operator.